# How to convert a Rational into a "pretty" String?

Tags: haskell, formatting, rational-number

I want to display some `Rational` values in their decimal expansion.  That is, instead of displaying `3 % 4`, I would rather display `0.75`.  I'd like this function to be of type `Int -> Rational -> String`.  The first `Int` is to specify the maximum number of decimal places, since `Rational` expansions may be non-terminating.

[Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int%20-%3E%20Rational%20-%3E%20String) and the [haddocks for Data.Ratio](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html) didn't help me.  Where can I find this function?

Comment: Converting to a `RealFloat` using `Numeric.fromRat` and then showing the float using `Numeric.show*Float` functions isn't an option?

Comment: Are you sure you _need_ `Rational`, when you only want a decimal approximation in the end?

Comment: The decimal approximation is only to make debugging easier.  And I want up to thousands of digits of accuracy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an arbitrary precision solution that doesn't use floats:

```hs
import Data.Ratio

display :: Int -> Rational -> String
display len rat = (if num < 0 then "-" else "") ++ (shows d ("." ++ take len (go next)))
    where
        (d, next) = abs num `quotRem` den
        num = numerator rat
        den = denominator rat

        go 0 = ""
        go x = let (d, next) = (10 * x) `quotRem` den
               in shows d (go next)
```

Comment: If no one comes along with a standard library solution I'll accept this.

Answer (score 10):

You can make it. Not elegant, but does the job:

```
import Numeric
import Data.Ratio

display :: Int -> Rational -> String
display n x = (showFFloat (Just n) $ fromRat x) ""
```

Answer (score 8):

Arbitrary precision version that re-uses [library code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers-3000.2.0.1/docs/Data-Number-CReal.html):

```
import Data.Number.CReal

display :: Int -> Rational -> String
display digits num = showCReal digits (fromRational num)
```

I know I've seen a function before that converts rationals into digits in a way that's easier to inspect (i.e. that makes it quite clear where the digits start repeating), but I can't seem to find it now. In any case, it's not hard to write, if that turns out to be a need; you just code up the usual long-division algorithm and watch for divisions you've already done.

Comment: Does `fromRational` end up using some kind of floating point here?

Comment: @StevenShaw It uses [`CReal`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers-3000.2.0.2/docs/Data-Number-CReal.html), as foreshadowed by the hyperlink, the import, and the call to `showCReal`. `CReal` is not floating point; it is arbitrary precision, with the precision determined by the consumer, not the producer as traditional floating point types (arbitrary precision or otherwise).

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! It wasn't super clear from the docs of the package. I've not heard of constructive/computable real numbers before. I looked into the sources after I messaged you, and it became a little clearer that it was arbitrary precision :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one that I wrote a few weeks ago.  You can specify the number of decimals you want (correctly rounded), or just pass `Nothing` in which case it will print the full precision, including marking the repeated decimals.

```
module ShowRational where
import Data.List(findIndex, splitAt)

-- | Convert a 'Rational' to a 'String' using the given number of decimals.
-- If the number of decimals is not given the full precision is showed using (DDD) for repeating digits.
-- E.g., 13.7/3 is shown as \"4.5(6)\".
showRational :: Maybe Int -> Rational -> String
showRational (Just n) r =
    let d = round (abs r * 10^n)
        s = show (d :: Integer)
        s' = replicate (n - length s + 1) '0' ++ s
        (h, f) = splitAt (length s' - n) s'
    in  (if r < 0 then "-" else "") ++ h ++ "." ++ f
-- The length of the repeating digits is related to the totient function of the denominator.
-- This means that the complexity of computing them is at least as bad as factoring, i.e., it quickly becomes infeasible.
showRational Nothing r =
    let (i, f) = properFraction (abs r) :: (Integer, Rational)
        si = if r < 0 then "-" ++ show i else show i
        decimals f = loop f [] ""
        loop x fs ds =
            if x == 0 then
                ds
            else
                case findIndex (x ==) fs of
                    Just i  -> let (l, r) = splitAt i ds in l ++ "(" ++ r ++ ")"
                    Nothing -> let (c, f) = properFraction (10 * x) :: (Integer, Rational) in loop f (fs ++ [x]) (ds ++ show c)
    in  if f == 0 then si else si ++ "." ++ decimals f
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import Data.List as L
import Data.Ratio

display :: (Integral i, Show i) => Int -> Ratio i -> String
display len rat = (if num < 0 then "-" else "") ++ show ip ++ "." ++ L.take len (go (abs num - ip * den))
  where
    num = numerator rat
    den = denominator rat
    ip  = abs num `quot` den

    go 0 = ""
    go x = shows d (go next)
      where
        (d, next) = (10 * x) `quotRem` den
```